# Kivy can't round the button

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd, kivy-recycleview

## I've already watched a lot of videos and don't understand why the rounding doesn't work.

I get the following buttons:

[image: I get the following buttons]

And we need these:

[image: and we need these]

main.py:

```
Window.size = (430, 930)

class Container(BoxLayout):
    pass

class KivyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Container()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    KivyApp().run()`

Kivy.kv
`
<Container>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Image: 
        source: "BACKGROUND.png"

    BoxLayout:
        padding: 20
        spacing: 20
        size_hint: 1, 0.5

        Button:
            text: 'New Button'
            background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
            background_normal: ''
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 96/255, 21/255, 21/255, 0.50
                RoundedRectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
                    radius: [50]
                Color:
                    rgba: 168/255, 0/255, 0/255, 1
                Line:
                    width: 2
                    rectangle: (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)
        
        Button:
            text: 'New Button'
            background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
            background_normal: ''
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 42/255, 59/255, 79/255, 0.50
                RoundedRectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
                    radius: [10]
                Color:
                    rgba: 121/255, 158/255, 225/255, 1
                Line:
                    width: 2
                    rectangle: (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)

        Button:
            text: 'New Button'
            background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
            background_normal: ''
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 136/255, 255/255, 134/255, 0.31
                RoundedRectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
                    radius: [10]
                Color:
                    rgba: 123/255, 255/255, 121/255, 1
                Line:
                    width: 2
                    rectangle: (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)`




`RoundedRectangle:
      pos: self.pos
      size: self.size
      radius: [10]
```

I tried to round it up, everything seems to be correct, but for some reason it doesn't work
I looked through a lot of articles on stackowerflow but nothing helped me to round it off

Answer (score 0):

You just need to round the `Line` you are using to outline the `Button`:

Try changing:

```
            Line:
                width: 2
                rectangle: (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)
```

to:

```
            Line:
                width: 2
                rounded_rectangle: (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height, 50)
```